# The CSS file loading issue in a mobile safari browser

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, mobile-safari

I created the website by using reactJs, nodeJs (express server). Customers are happy and so on but ... there is the issue which is reproducible by a few customers (I can't reproduce it). It seems this issue occur only on iPhone devices (safari browser). 
After a customer logged in to the system the blank page is displayed (so, css not loaded correctly). Error message:
**Did not parse stylesheet at ... because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.**

The facts:

- After page refresh everything is ok, css is loaded without errors
- By using *private mode* of the browser - everything ok
- Content type of the response - "text/css; charset=UTF-8"
- Css is added to html header tag like this:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.b68c3443.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

- User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
- If a customer clear browser cache - everything ok for a few times

Workflow:

1. customer enter credentials in the login page
2. redirect to the loading page (css file must be loaded), here is react app placed. path: /login
3. react app redirects to home page (page is not reloaded), path: /home

Request info:

```
"request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "<domain here>/static/css/main.b68c3443.css",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [

            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "text/css,*/*;q=0.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://<domain here>/login"
            },
            {
              "name": "DNT",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "<domain here>"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "da-dk"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "br, gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "headersSize": 589,
          "bodySize": 0
        }
```

Response info:

```
 "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "cookies": [],
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/css; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Ranges",
              "value": "bytes"
            },
            {
              "name": "Pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Expires",
              "value": "-1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
              "value": "Identity"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Fri, 25 Jan 2019 11:16:01 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
              "value": "true"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "ETag",
              "value": "ef9275a5-7313-4124-b4f9-aac59d8d35bd"
            },
            {
              "name": "Vary",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Last-Modified",
              "value": "Fri, 25 Jan 2019 08:16:41 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Powered-By",
              "value": "Express"
            },
            {
              "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
              "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
            }
          ],
          "content": {
            "size": 58191,
            "compression": 0,
            "mimeType": "text/css",
            "text": "@font-face{ <css content> /*# sourceMappingURL=main.b68c3443.css.map*/"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 498,
          "bodySize": 58191,
          "_transferSize": 58689
        },
        "cache": {},
        "_fetchType": "Network Load"
      }
```

I thought it is somehow related with a browser caching, so I tried disable caching only for iPhone devices but no luck. It is very difficult to debug because I can't reproduce on my test iphones.
What I didn't try yet - to remove *Accept-Ranges* from response headers. Maybe this header can be the cause of problem  ?
Do you have any ideas ?
An idea to add styles to inline html page is very ugly solution...